# jQuery If slect option label = ... set input value

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have select and some inputs (range + text). I need to do when I choose one of select, input get values but the code works only with first choice. When I change my choice value doesn't changed. What should I correct?

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $("div.roword select").change( function() {
        var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        if (text = "60x90") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").attr('value', '60');
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").attr('value', '90');
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
            } else 
        if (text = "100x150") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").attr('value', '100');
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").attr('value', '150');
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
            } else 
        if (text = "120x180") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").attr('value', '120');
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").attr('value', '180');
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `==`/`===` comparison operator  instead of `=` assignment operator in if block i.e. `text === "100x150"` and to set value use `.val()` method i.e. `$("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(90)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert:-

```
if (text = "60x90") {
```

To:-

```
if (text == "60x90") { //or if (text === "60x90") {
```

And so-on for others

Because `=` is ***assignment-operator***  not ***comparison-operator***.

***And***

change

```
$("input#height, input#heightPlus").attr('value', '60');
```

To:-

```
$("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(60);
```

So-on for other `attr('value')` also......

**Complete code need to be like this:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $("div.roword select").change( function() {
        var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        if (text == "60x90") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(60);
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(90);
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
        }
        else if (text == "100x150") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(100);
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(150);
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
        }
        else if(text == "120x180") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(120);
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(180);
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
        }
    });
});
```